# Record distance moved and new lat/long in attribute table after snapping points to line

Tags: qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.6. I have a dataset of fish locations (points) that I snapped to a river (line). I would like to add the distance each point moved to the attributes table, as well as the new lat/long. As there are several hundred fish localities, I would like to do this as a batch after snapping them all rather than manually measure the distances between each pair of points.

Comment: Sounds simple enough, so long as you preserve the ID and previous lat/lon values, the all you need to do is calculate the spheroidal distance from lat1/lon1 to lat2/lon2.

Comment: It is likely that I am missing something, but the new attribute table for the results layer has the same old lat/lon listed. How can I get those to measure with? And then how do I measure the spheroidal distance between the whole set of lat1/lon1 and lat2/lon2? I can't find how to do that...

Comment: It's dirt-simple with the ArcGIS Projection Engine, one feature at a time in a cursor; you need to find the QGIS equivalent (possibly by generating line features and calculating their length). But first you need to extract the new positions (again, simple with Esri tools, so it shouldn't be too hard).

Comment: Clarification, please:  1. what do you mean by "snapped"?  2. Did that snapping create a second point layer, or did it move the fish point layer? 3. If you did create a second point layer, does it contain an attribute field that allows you to link each new point to its parent? 4. Where do you want to store the distance and location data - original point layer, second point layer, river layer, or standalone attribute table?